# recognize_google(audio) filters out bad words

Tags: python, speech-recognition

I'm facing this problem with google speech_recognition api. It automatically filters out bad words and returns a string like "F***" or "P******"

Here is my code. There is no error in my code but please help how do I get a raw converted text from my audio.

```
    from gtts import gTTS
    import speech_recognition as sr

    r = sr.Recognizer()

with sr.Microphone() as source:
    print('Ready...')
    r.pause_threshold = 1
    r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source, duration=1)
    audio = r.listen(source)

    command = r.recognize_google(audio).lower()
    print('You said: ' + command + '\n')
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> [profanity_filter](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/speech/gapic/v1/types.html#google.cloud.speech_v1.types.RecognitionConfig.profanity_filter)
>
> Optional If set to true, the server will attempt to filter out profanities, replacing all but the initial character in each filtered word with asterisks, e.g. “f***”. If set to false or omitted, profanities won’t be filtered out.

Search:
https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/search.html?q=profanity_filter&check_keywords=yes&area=default

Example:

https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/speech/index.html?highlight=profanity_filter#synchronous-recognition

> Example of using the profanity filter.
>
> ```
> >>> from google.cloud import speech
> >>> client = speech.SpeechClient()
> >>> results = client.recognize(
> ...     audio=speech.types.RecognitionAudio(
> ...         uri='gs://my-bucket/recording.flac',
> ...     ),
> ...     config=speech.types.RecognitionConfig(
> ...         encoding='LINEAR16',
> ...         language_code='en-US',
> ...         profanity_filter=True,
> ...         sample_rate_hertz=44100,
> ...     ),
> ... )
> >>> for result in results:
> ...     for alternative in result.alternatives:
> ...         print('=' * 20)
> ...         print('transcript: ' + alternative.transcript)
> ...         print('confidence: ' + str(alternative.confidence))
> ====================
> transcript: Hello, this is a f****** test
> confidence: 0.81
> ```

Nice example ;-)

(I have not tested this)